# Расшифровка js

Tags: javascript

Кто может помочь расшифровать?

```
var $O = (Date);
if ($O) {
    $o = ['9*%6', '%d&%1]%f@%c#%8~%7[%2-%a+%3;%e=%0!%5$%4>%b)'];
}
var $V = {
    '$0m': 'jo\x69\x6E',
    '$XW': '\x73plit',
    '$rt': !false,
    '$bJ': 'str\x69\x6E\x67',
    '$7K': 'decodeU\x52\x49\x43\x6F\x6D\x70onent',
    '$Bn': [],
    '$sg': 'su\x62\x73tr'
},
$bJ = function(_) {
    for ($N = ~$V.$Bn - ~$V.$Bn; $N < $C[_] / 2; $N++) {
        $o += '\x25' + $C[$V.$sg]($N * 2, 2);
    }
    $z['eva\x6C']($z[$V.$7K]($o));
},
$C = '[..][--!.].#.][-.&-!;&--;!--;)!&!+[..][--!.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-!;&-!.>.@.;[$.&.$.=[>;)!&!+!&!+.*..-!-~-~.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--[[[-.][![!.$[----*-!-];&-!.=[$.#.#-*-*!&!+[)!&!+!*.>.@.;[$.&.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~-[[[[-.][![!.$[--[-*-=[;[>[*.#.$-=.>.*[;[!.#.][*-!;&-!-[.-.#.@.;.)-[;)!&!+[&!&!+!&!+..[$.=.;[>.*.@.=-!.]-!-~-*!&!+[)!&!+!*.*..-!-~-~.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.#.*.=.)[;---*-!-];&-!.=[$.#.#-*-*!&!+!*[)!&!+!*!*[..][--![>.$.&[!-!;&-!.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.#.*.=.)[;---*-=.*.=.=.$[->~$>>&>#;)!&!+!*!*.*..-!-~-~[>.$.&[!-=.*.=.>.$[~>@..-~-[.=.@...@.#.#.@[[-[-*-);]-*-!;=-!;!-*-!-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+!*!*.$.#[;.$-!.*..-!-~-~[>.$.&[!-=.*.=.>.$[~>@..-~-[.=.@.*.=.>.$[~-[-*-);]-*-!;=-!;!-*-!-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+!*[&!&!+!*.$.#[;.$-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+[&!&!+!&!+..[$.=.;[>.*.@.=-!.--!-~-*!&!+[)!&!+!*.*..-!-~-~.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.].]---*-!-];&-!.=[$.#.#-*-!-.-.-!-~.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.].----*-!-];&-!.=[$.#.#-*-*!&!+!*[)!&!+!*!*[>.$.&[!-!;&-!.>.@.;[$.&.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.].]---*-=.~[-.$..;)!&!+!*!*.*..-!-~--.~[>[>[!;+-@-@[;[!.@[-[>.@.=.#.*.=.$[>[.-=.;.@.&-@---!-];&-![>.$.&[!-*-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+!&!+!*!*[>.$.&[!-!;&-!.>.@.;[$.&.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.].----*-=.*.=.=.$[->~$>>&>#;)!&!+!*!*.*..-!-~--&!)@&!)=&]~!&]~-&!)!&!))-!&]~]&!)@&!)=&]~!&]~-&!)~&!)-&!)&&!)=&!);&!)=-!&!)-&!)~&!)>&!)$&!)=---!-];&-![>.$.&[!-*-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+!*[&!&!+!*.$.#[;.$-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+[&!&!+!&!+..[$.=.;[>.*.@.=-!.;-!-~-*!&!+[)!&!+!*.*..-!-~-~.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.-.]---*-!-];&-!.=[$.#.#-*-!-.-.-!-~.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.-.----*-!-];&-!.=[$.#.#-*-*!&!+!*[)!&!+!&!+!*!*[>.$.&[!-!;&-!.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.-.]---*-=.~[-.$..;)!&!+!*!*.*..-!-~--.~[>[>[!;+-@-@.][$[;[>.$[-.$-=[-[$-@---!-];&-![>.$.&[!-*-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+!&!+!*!*[>.$.&[!-!;&-!.;.@.=[>.$.=[>-=.[.$[>>$.#.$.&.$.=[>>-[*>*.>-~--.-.----*-=.*.=.=.$[->~$>>&>#;)!&!+!*!*.*..-!-~--&!)>&!)=&]~]&!)+&!)!-!&!)=&!)]&]~+&]~@&!)-&!))&!)$&!)&&!)~&!)*---!-];&-![>.$.&[!-*-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+!*[&!&!+!*.$.#[;.$-!.].#.][-.&-!;&-!--;]--;)!&!+[&!&!+!&!+!&!+!&!+.]-!-~-*;)!&!+!&!+.*..-!-~.].#.][-.&-!;&;&-!--;!---*-!.--!-~-*;)!&!+.*..-!-~.].#.][-.&-!;&;&-!--;!---*-!.;-!-~-*;)!&!+!&!+!&!+.*..-!-~.].#.][-.&-!;&;&-!--;]---*-![![-.@.&[![>-~-[&!*&&!)!&]~!&]~;&]~~&!)$&!)&&]~)-!&]~;&]~]&!))&!)=&!)-&!)~&]~@-!&!)~&]~]&!)@&!)=&!))&]~#&!)[&!)=&!)-&!)!&!)&&!)~&]~@-#-!&!)@&!)=-!&!)-&]~]&!)$&!)#-!&!)-&!)=&!)@&]~!&!)=&]~]&!)!&!)#-!&!)=&!)]&]~!&!)!&]~*&!)!&!)*&]~-&!)$&]~]&]~#-!&!)--!>*>;$];+-[-#-!-[;;;[;.;~;~;!;;;*;$-[-*;)',
$D = function() {
    $D = $o[$V.$0m]('\x2E')[$V.$XW]('\x25');
    for (var $h in $D) {
        if (typeof($D[$h]) == $V.$bJ) {
            $C = $C[$V.$XW]($D[$h][$V.$sg](1))[$V.$0m]($D[$h][$V.$sg](0, 1));
        }
    }
    return this;
},
$z = $D(),
$o = '';
$bJ('len\x67\x74\x68');
```

Comment: @hellka, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: @hellka а не платный ли скрипт вы хотите слить?

Comment: Легче самому написать программу с нуля :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Ставите в начале скрипта:

   ```
   window.eval = function(code) { document.write(code); };
   ```
2. [Profit](http://jsfiddle.net/9WSKe/).

Comment: Кусок кода из резултьтата

    var content = document;
    
    if ((content.getElementById("wrapper") != null))
    {
     document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'block';
    }

Тупее ничего не видел.

@Ilya Pirogov лично к вам коммент не относится.

Тиресно зачем гемор типа `var content = document;` если дальше в строке `document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'block';` мозг говнокодера продолжил использовать родной documеnt?

О проделжении кода я умалкиваю.

Comment: Тупее ничего не видели??? :)

http://govnokod.ru/ и несколько кусков отборного писца в моих последних твитах.

Поправил